# Integrales definidas en python - Area bajo curva normal estandar

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo dos arrays con valores x e y, "x" (valor de variable aleatoria) son valores de entrada, e "y" son valores calculados en función de x (función de densidad de probabilidad normal para x) . Cómo puedo calcular la integral de "y" para un rango de valores en "x". He visto como hacerlo, pero todos implican la escritura de la función en forma abstracta y la de la distribución normal es complicada.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

# valores-puntos (x,y) de la función
x=np.linspace(-4,4,num=1000)
y=st.norm.pdf(x,0,1)
print(x,y)
```

Me gustaría calcular la integral entre -1 y 0 por ejemplo. Acaso mi unica alternativa es escribir la función como `f=lambda x: f(x)` y usar `integrate.quad(f,lb,ub)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas escribir la función analíticamente, si es lo que te preocupa. Basta que tengas alguna forma de computar el valor de `y`, dado `x`. Entonces a `integrate.quad` le pasas el nombre de esa función. Y precisamente eso es lo que hace la función `st.norm.pdf()`, ¿no?

Si la media es 0 y la desviación es 1, no necesitas pasarle esos parámetros (pues son los que asume por defecto). Así, por ejemplo, la integral entre -1 y 0 sería:

```
>>> integrate.quad(st.norm.pdf, -1, 0)
(0.341344746068543, 3.789687964201238e-15)
```

En caso de que quieras pasarle una media y desviación distintas de las que usa por defecto, puedes programar una función lambda bastante trivial, por ejemplo, para media=1, desviación=2

```
>>> integrate.quad(lambda x: st.norm.pdf(x, 1, 2), -1, 0)
(0.14988228479452986, 1.6640276356231206e-15)
```

O si no te gusta usar lambdas, define tu propia función aparte y pásasela a `integrate.quad()`:

```
>>> def mydist(x):
...   return st.norm.pdf(x, 1, 2)
...
>>> integrate.quad(mydist, -1, 0)
(0.14988228479452986, 1.6640276356231206e-15)
```

Comment: Gracias :D me solcionó todo :D